# Button and Widget size in Kivy (KivyMD)

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

Good Morning,
I work on my cross-platform app project. I've got a trouble with size management in **KivyMD**.
I would like to change the size and position of my widgets as well as this I want to set `size_hint` into `(None, None)` in order to have a right working on cross-platform devices. I try to change the size with `size` parameter but this only works on the y-axis. X-axis is still in the beginning position. I would like to ask about another widgets like *icons*, *FloatLayout* layers how to set `size_hint` to `None` and also change the size in order to have a right working on cross-platform devices.[image]

```py
#: import utils kivy.utils
MDScreen:
    name: "LoginPage"
    on_enter:
        app.animationBack1(back1)
        app.animationBack2(back2)
        app.animationIcon(userIcon)
        app.animationLoginLabel(loginLabel)

MDFloatLayout:
    MDFloatLayout:
        id: back1
        size_hint_y: .3
        pos_hint: {'center_y': 1.5}
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgb: utils.get_color_from_hex('#74A3FC')

            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos

    MDFloatLayout:
        id: back2
        size_hint_y: .6
        pos_hint: {'center_y': 1.5}
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgb: utils.get_color_from_hex('#74A3FC') # most
            Ellipse:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos

    MDIcon:
        id: userIcon
        halign: 'center'
        icon: 'account-circle'
        font_size: '70sp'
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .75}
        opacity: 0 # visibility

    MDLabel:
        id: loginLabel
        text: '[size=60][b]Login Page[/b][/size]'
        markup: True
        halign: 'center'
        pos_hint: {'center_y': .8}
        opacity: 0 # visibility

    MDTextField:
        id: email
        hint_text: 'Enter Email'
        required: True
        helper_text_mode: 'on_error'
        helper_text: 'Please, enter Your Email.'
        color_mode: 'custom'
        line_color_focus: utils.get_color_from_hex('#74A3FC')
        current_hint_text_color: utils.get_color_from_hex('#74A3FC') # can be, otherwise after running app, hint_text will be grey
            # after error rasing hint_text will be also customized
        size: 800, 1
        size_hint: None, None
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .45}

    MDTextField:
        id: password
        hint_text: 'Enter Password'
        password: True
        required: True
        helper_text_mode: 'on_error'
        helper_text: 'Please, enter Your Password.'
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .3}
        size: 800, 1
        size_hint: (None, None)
        line_color_focus: utils.get_color_from_hex('#74A3FC')
        current_hint_text_color: utils.get_color_from_hex('#74A3FC')
        color_mode: 'custom' # must be, otherwise on the second click line color 
will customized

    MDFillRoundFlatButton:
        text: 'Login'
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': 0.05}
        size: 800, 100
        size_hint: (None, None) #text never leaves the button-I don't know why
        # theme_text_color: 'Error' #['Primary', 'Secondary', 'Hint', 'Error', 'Custom', 'ContrastParentBackground'] - only change text color
        md_bg_color: utils.get_color_from_hex('#74A3FC')
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, took way too long to search for answers online. Finally read the source code in `.../python3.10/site-packages/kivymd/uix/button/button.py`, and found this workaround for KivyMD 1.1.1 using `_min_width` and `_min_height`:

```
MDFillRoundFlatButton:
        text: 'Login'
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': 0.05}
        md_bg_color: utils.get_color_from_hex('#74A3FC')
        _min_width:  800
        _min_height: 100
```